# Как объединить функции ЕСЛИ и IMPORTHTML?

Tags: excel, google-docs

Помогите объединить работу функций `ЕСЛИ` и `IMPORTHTML` в гугл таблице

**Задача:**

Если в ячейке `B1` стоит `Самара` то необходимо применять функцию `=IMPORTHTML("https://yandex.ru/pogoda/samara/details?via=ms";"table";1)`

Если в `B1` - `Тюмень` то возвращать

`=IMPORTHTML("https://yandex.ru/pogoda/tyumen/details?via=ms";"table";1)`

и так далее...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ЕСЛИ(B1="Самара";IMPORTHTML("https://yandex.ru/pogoda/samara/details?via=ms";"table";1);IMPORTHTML("https://yandex.ru/pogoda/tyumen/details?via=ms";"table";1))
```

Или

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://yandex.ru/pogoda/"&ЕСЛИ(B1="Самара";"samara";"tyumen"))&"/details?via=ms";"table";1)
```

Если города могут быть другие: составить таблицу соответствий (первый столбец - город, второй - фрагмент для ссылки) и из нее подтягивать данные в формулу. Вместо функции `ЕСЛИ`:

```
=ВПР(B1;таблица_соответствий;2;0)
```

Comment: Первый вариант нужен пример, у меня ошибки в синтаксисе получаются. Во втором варианте как подставить другие города? Пустая ячейка не бывает вместо Тюмени или Самары может быть любой город Саратов - saratov и т д.

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Изменил первую формулу